# Spacing of rotated elements (labels) in grid

Tags: grid-layouts, rotation, size, spacing

How can I change the size of a specific subset of cells in a `Grid`? I'm using the `ItemSize` parameter for the ones I want to change, but it affects others, and I can't control the sizes separately.

More detail: I want to present a large matrix (48x48) with labels for each column and row. The way I'm doing it right now is with `Grid`, by adding an extra row and column with the desired labels. However, since the entries are of varying lengths, I want to adjust the size of these `Grid` cells so that they're all the same - but I want to leave the label cells unchanged.

Here is (a MWE of) my code to begin with:

```
labels = {"Long property name A", "Extremely long Property name B"};
Grid[Partition[Riffle[Join[
    {Null},
    Item[Rotate[#, -90 Degree], Alignment -> Bottom] & /@ labels,
    {1, 3000, 5, 7000}],
   Item[#, Alignment -> Right] & /@ labels, {4, -1, 3}], 3], 
 Frame -> All]
```

This is the result:

[image]

Now, I would like to change the size of the cells in the bottom right 4x4 submatrix, so that they all have the same size. I fix this by changing the table entry `{1,3000,5,7000}` to:

```
Item[#, ItemSize -> 4] & /@ {1, 3000, 5, 7000}
```

But then this is the result:

[image]

I tried adding the `ItemSize` parameter to the `Item`s containing the labels, but the label text appears in a single line only if the cell is extremely wide, such as `ItemSize->20`, which I don't want. So - how can I change the size of some of the cells without affecting the size of other cells?

Answer (score 1):

Cheating by using Rasterize

```
labels = {"Long property name A", "Extremely long Property name B"};
Grid[Partition[
  Riffle[Join[{Null}, 
    Item[Rasterize[Item[Rotate[#, -90 Degree]]], 
       Alignment -> Bottom] & /@ labels, 
    Item[#, ItemSize -> 4] & /@ {1, 3000, 5, 7000}], 
   Item[#, Alignment -> Right] & /@ labels, {4, -1, 3}], 3], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

No claim made that this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but when I run your code, the longer vertical name gets scaled down and is much smaller than the other one, see here: https://imgur.com/vK09aQJ I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but Rasterize slowed down rendering a large grid significantly. Another workaround is to wrap your text in Row. It's maybe faster, more flexible.

```
labels = {"Long property name A", "Extremely long Property name B"};
Grid[Partition[
  Riffle[Join[{Null}, 
    Rotate[Row[{#}, ImageSize->{230, 20}, Alignment->{Right, Center}], -90 Degree]& /@ labels, 
    Item[#, ItemSize -> 4] & /@ {1, 3000, 5, 7000}], 
   Item[#, Alignment -> Right] & /@ labels, {4, -1, 3}], 3], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image: grid with rotated text]

You'll need to specify the ImageSize for Row. Its width is the column header height and right align puts it at the bottom when rotated.